# How to add such function in dll?

Tags: file, function, dll, syntax, stream

I make a `dll` and its using by [this tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm). I make absolutely the same files with the same code. Ok. It works just fine. Now I add my function with #include vector, using namespace std and fsream of course:

```
DECLDIR void toFileWrite(vector<int> v, const char *fName)
{
    ofstream inf;

    inf.open(fName,inf.trunc);      
    if (inf!=NULL)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i=i+2)
        {       
            inf << v.at(i)<<"\t"<<v.at(i+1)<<"\n";
        }   
    }       
    inf.close();        
}
```

Building a release causes no problems.
Then, exactly by the author model, I add using of my function in my application.

But when I call it I got error window with text: "Unhandled exception at0x7855db75 in a.exe: Access violation reading location 0x2982d311"
VS opens cpp-file of my dll and points with green arrow to line: `if (inf!=NULL)`

So, what the author didn't mention, and what I should do to make such **a simple function work properly**?

Comment: Can you post the function call ? how do you call this function ? 
One thing to do, is put a breakpoint at `toFileWrite(...)` and step in , then check parameters.

Comment: `vector<int> a(4,100);
_toFileWriteFunc(a,"hey.txt");`

Comment: on my MACOS the code works fine, 
How do you load that DLL ? Do you call LoadLibrary then GetProcAddress ? 
Can you put breakpoint at `if (inf.open)` and check the whole inf structure after open call ?